# Show that $m+3$ and $m^2 + 3m +3$ cannot both be perfect cubes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Show that $m+3$ and $m^2 + 3m +3$ cannot both be perfect cubes.

I've done so much algebra on this, but no luck. Tried multiplying, factoring, etc.

Comment: Jared, why on earth are you trying to post this in meta? It is off-topic there. Meta is not for discussion of math - it is for discussions on how to run the site math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Total accident. I have no idea how I wound up in Meta. I don't even know what Meta is. Sorry!

Comment: After substituting $n=m+1$, this appears the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71412

Answer (score 12):

If they were, $$(m+3)(m^2+3m+3)=(m+2)^3+1$$
would be a perfet cube. There aren't many perfect cubes that differ by $1$:
$n^3-(m+2)^3=1$ means $m+2-n\mid1$ and hence $n=m+2\pm1$, reducing the equation to two quadratics: $3(m+2)^2+3(m+2)=0$ and $-3(m+2)^2+3(m+2)-2=0$. This shows that the only value where the statement fails is $m=-2$.

Comment: Nice! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: So annoying. I had it! I multiplied them both to see what they would produce, but didn't recognize the factorization. I should have used an algebra program next time to check before asking here I guess. It's depressing.

Comment: The only perfect cubes that differ by $1$ are $-1,0,1$ and it's trivial if you notice that $$(n+1)^3-n^3=3n^3+3n+1=1\iff 3n(n+1)(n-1)=0$$ Just showing a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

The first observation is that $m=-2$ is a counterexample. Presumably $m$ should be non-negative.

Assume that $m+3=n^3$ is a perfect cube. Then $n>1$ and
$$
m^2+3m+3=n^6-3n^3+3.
$$
This is strictly less than $n^6=(n^2)^3$. The previous cube below this is
$$
(n^2-1)^3=n^6-3n^4+3n^2-1,
$$
which is $<n^6-3n^3+3$ as $n\ge2$. Therefore $m^2+3m+3$ is strictly between two consecutive perfect cubes, and cannot be a perfect cube itself.

Comment: Clever.  Is there an immediate way to see $n^6-3n^4+3n^2-1<n^6-3n^3+3$, for $n\geq2$?  I can prove it by taking a derivative, but is there a more obvious way to see it?

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Admittedly I did something similar. Checking it with smallest possible values of $n$, and then relying on the quartic growing faster than the cubic.

Comment: @GregoryGrant The claimed inequality follows from $n^4>n^3+n^2$ which is true for $n\ge 2$ because $n^4\ge2n^3>n^3+n^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false: for $m=-2$, we have $m+3=m^2+3m+3=1$.

Comment: (This follows from reflecting on @barto's answer.)