# Problems & Solutions on Fermat Theorem of Multiple of 3

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am working on an assignment in *elementary* number theory, in which I have to come up with original problems and then work out their solutions on Fermat theorem of multiple of 3, that is, the equation
$$x^3 + y^3 = z^3$$
does not have integer solution for $xyz \neq 0$.

The first problem that I came up easily is one requiring readers to prove that $x^6 + y^6 = z^6$ does not have integer solution, which is very straightforward. But I need more than just one problem. I have searched around in the internet for ideas but could not find any. Therefore here is my question:

Do you have any ideas, suggestion, links or hints that perhaps can help me with writing couple more question related to the subject? Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790600/how-do-i-prove-the-following-result-in-number-theory or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71412/show-that-n-2-and-n2-n-1-cannot-both-be-perfect-cubes or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190931/show-that-m3-and-m2-3m-3-cannot-both-be-perfect-cubes?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve in integers $\left(a-b\right)\left(a^2-b^2\right)\left(a^3-b^3\right)=3c^3$.

To solve it, notice $(3c)^3=(a^2-2b^2+ab)^3 + (2a^2-b^2-ab)^3$,

so either $c=0$ or $a^2-2b^2+ab=0$ or $2a^2-b^2-ab=0$.

[Here's where I found the problem](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c146706h1152733_problem_of_the_day_101715).

---

$$(a-b)\left(a^2-b^2\right)\left(a^3-b^3\right)=(a-b)^3(a+b)\left(a^2+ab+b^2\right)$$

$a^2+ab+b^2=\left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3b^2}{4}\ge 0$ with equality if and only if $a=b=0$.

If $c=0$, then either $a=b$ or $a=-b$, so $(a,b,c)=(k,k,0),(k,-k,0)$, $k\in\mathbb Z$.

If $a^2-2b^2+ab=0$, then $(2a+b)^2=9b^2$, so $2a+b=\pm 3b$.

If $2a+b=3b$, then $a=b$, so $(a,b,c)=(k,k,0)$.

If $2a+b=-3b$, then $a=-2b$, so $(a,b,c)=\left(-2k,k,3k^2\right)$.

If $2a^2-b^2-ab=0$, then $b^2-2a^2+ab=0$ (symmetrical to the other case), so analogously $(a,b,c)=(k,k,0),\left(k,-2k,-3k^2\right)$.

All solutions are $(a,b,c)=(k,k,0),(k,-k,0),(-2k,k,3k^2),(k,-2k,-3k^2)$.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I can give you more than one up-vote.