# How do I prove the following result in number theory?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

There exist no $(n, m) ∈ \mathbb{N}$ so that $n + 3m$ and $n
^2 + 3m^2$ both are
perfect cubes.

Comment: Also,  Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it.

Comment: Compare with [Show that $n + 2$ and $n^2 + n + 1$ cannot both be perfect cubes](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71412/show-that-n-2-and-n2-n-1-cannot-both-be-perfect-cubes)

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595262/problems-solutions-on-fermat-theorem-of-multiple-of-3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose they are.  Then  $(n+3m)(n^2+3m^2)$ is a perfect cube.

$(n+3m)(n^2+3m^2) = (n+m)^3 + (2m)^3$

Comment: Great! +1 Don't add anything and hopefully @MXYMXY will delete his comment, so that people can deduce that by themseleves

Comment: A neat solution!

Comment: @MXYMXY Citing Fermat's Last Theorem for the relatively simple case of $a^3+b^3=c^3$ is overkill. See http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.lt/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-proof-for-n3.html for an elementary proof.

Comment: @user236182 Now *you* need to delete your comment so that people can deduce either case.

Comment: @Joanpemo It is not a require to make people deduce the case, though I do think that it would be advisable in this case.

Comment: This solution reminds me of [this one of another diophantine equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595262/problems-solutions-on-fermat-theorem-of-multiple-of-3/1595273#1595273).

Comment: @MXYMXY Thank you. I know, yet I think it can be nice to see that, or at least to have someone "why is that a proof"?

Comment: @Joanpemo I respect you opinion, though it does differ from mine. I just thought the use of the word 'need' in the upper comment sounded a bit forceful. Doesn't matter though.